# X-FI optical output not being recognized

Tags: sound-card, spdif

I have an issue and I don't know what to do!

I have a SoundBlaster X-FI Xtreme Gamer, which has a spdif mini-optical output. I have it connected to a home theater, via a toslink cable and an adapter to fit in the mini plug.

It used to work perfectly, but now it doesn't anymore.

There is light travelling through the cable, but the HT doesn't pick up the signal. The sound card of the motherboard also has an optical output (regular, not mini) and it works ok, so the cable and the HT are fine, I think. 
What else should I try?

Thanks,
Luciano.

PS: I only enabled the onboard card for testing, but usually it's disabled to avoid any kind of conflicts.

PPS: I'm using Windows 7 64bit with latest drivers of everything, but like I said. It used to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I bought a new cable, normal toslink to mini plug (without adapters) and it's working. So I guess the adapter was the problem.